# Why aren't "keychainwrapper" and "FIRAuth" suggested to me and coloured?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I was trying to create an app, and while typing the codes on the program, I have noticed that

```
FIRAuth.auth().create
```

and the rest of the codes I have typed in my PodFile aren't suggested and coloured in the xcode program and that made me worried

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
pod 'SwiftKeychainWrapper'
```

thanks!

Comment: add import statement into file `import Fi` and pres control-space

Comment: If import statement doesnt work try restarting xcode, i have to do that once and awhile